# How to return the positions of a contour in a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, contour

I have a 2D matrix 50x50 constituted of a hole of '1' (a disk) and the remaining values are zero. (the matrix  is binary). I just would like to return the positions in the matrix of the contour of the object as shown in the figure below.

I tried the command "imcontour" (since my case is also a binary image). It is good but some of the given positions of the contour are above the size of the matrix , which means it maybe gives the position in pixels not index of the matrix.

I also tried "contour" and "boundary" but in vain.

[image]

Comment: `imcontour` should work, you certainly have a mistake in your code. Please provide a minimal exemple of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, try `[x,y]=find(M)` to extract positions and try `ind=find(M)` to extract index numbers of non-zeros values in your matrix. If you are looking for the boundary, just use bwperim function: `[x,y]=find(bwperim(M))`